# Is it possible to measure noise levels with the iPhone alone?

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app

It seems that you can't measure noise levels with the iPhone alone, you have to either connect an Apple Watch to it or Airpods, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environmental sound pressure monitoring is only a feature of the Apple Watch today in 2022.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/monitor-your-environmental-noise-exposure-apd1ecd70173/watchos

You would need an external microphone and this free app to get calibrated measurements from an iPhone alone.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/niosh-sound-level-meter/id1096545820

I’m not aware of other apps that took the time to try to calibrate their app, but I presume there are many other good apps if you go looking. This one has privacy attestations and write up that seem reliable to me. ([The same developer has a $1 app that may do a better job](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/noisee/id549239949) with a specific external mic or the built in sensors on the iPhone. )

Comment: Using the iPhone with the Airpods without an Apple watch also allows you to see the decibels without third party apps.

Comment: I really don't understand why Apple didn't make this feature available on the iphone alone, without third party apps.

Comment: I don’t know either. I really appreciate the watch phone integration, it’s phenomenally good. Perhaps the battery drain on the small watch is so much less than keeping the phone running, they discarded the idea to implement phone app as better to let some developers handle the phone and focus on the watch?